# Is it possible to configure Sublime Text 3 to insert a newline on some auto completions?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

The auto completion is pretty much default right now. If I type

```
<p{tab}
```

I get

```
<p></p>
```

Is it possible to configure it so that instead I end up with

```
<p>
</p>
```

This is just an example. I'd like it to be more comprehensive beyond just the `<p></p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've been doing it wrong. I've been looking at what happens only when I tab-complete a tag as in my example. It did not occur to me that simply pressing `enter` after the auto completion that it would actually set me up the way I would like and even better than I was asking for.

After pressing `enter` I end up with

```
<p>
  _
</p>
```

with the cursor (represented by the `_`) indented two spaces on the blank line.